# How to get images to go to 100% height with the style tag

Tags: html

How do I get the height to work, It doesn't affect the images on the Carousel (They change heights, but the width stays the same (obviously)

```
<div class="item">
        <img src="Slideshow2.jpg" alt="Alt Name" style="width:100%, height:100%;">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>Name</h3>
          <p>Context</p>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: Please don't use the style attribute because its unorganised.

Comment: If not that then what do I change it too?, The CSS answer didn't affect the images

Comment: try putting `!important` after the css styles that don't work, but using the style attribute is not as good as putting everything in one place

Answer (score 0):

```
img {
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

Add this to your CSS, then put it in the `<style>` tag or link to a css document using a `link` tag.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: The problem still persists even with this added the the img css